# HBase setMaxVersions java API doesn't work

Tags: java, api, hbase

I have a problem:
when I execute, with eclipse neon:

```
HTableDescriptor descriptor = new HTableDescriptor(TableName.valueOf("shoppingcart"));
HColumnDescriptor cd = new HColumnDescriptor(Bytes.toBytes("items"));
cd.setMaxVersions(4);
```

There is no change in hbase shell. If I execute:

```
decribe 'shoppingcart',
```

It returns VERSION: 3

This is my java code. Is that false? Or, did I misunderstand the HBase functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update on HColumnDescriptor is not propagated to HBase server. Add these lines:

```
HBaseAdmin hBaseAdmin = new HBaseAdmin(conf);
hBaseAdmin.modifyTable("shoppingcart", descriptor);
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you